# Getting java.io.FileNotFoundException: Failed to load keystore type JKS

Tags: java, docker, keystore, tomcat8

Hi I am setting up a old java project using docker and tomcat 8 in my Ubuntu 20.04 VM. after building image and running the container, I am getting java exception error of file not found `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore (No such file or directory)`

Although I have stored `tomcat.keystore` in the respective path `opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore`

So the full error is `SEVERE [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESocketFactory.getStore Failed to load keystore type JKS with path /opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore due to /opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore (No such file or directory)`

**in server.xml file**

```
<Connector port="8443"
                     protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                     maxThreads="150"
                     scheme="https"
                     secure="true"
                     SSLEnabled="true"
                     truststoreFile="/opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore"
                     truststorePass="xxxxx"
                     keystoreFile="/opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore"
                     keystorePass="xxxxx"
                     clientAuth="true"
                     keyAlias="serveralias"
                     sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Not able to crack the error exaclty.

**Update:-**

When I ran the container using `./run_dockers.sh` I found there is no exception errors after logging the container `docker logs --details <container_name>`

*run_docker.sh:-*

```
echo "Running container $DOCKNAME from image $IMGNAME"
    docker run -d \
            --restart=always \
            --publish 8080:8080 \
            --publish 8443:8443 \
            -v /opt/server:/opt/server \
            -v /opt/server/logs:/usr/local/tomcat/logs \
            --name=$DOCKNAME \
            $IMGNAME
```

Hitting localhost:8080 in browser I can see tomcat screen, but still unable to redirect to project url , localhost:8080/project_url - Showing 404 not found

Comment: What's the output of the following command `$ ls /opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore`?

Comment: It could be an issue of file permissions, check the user that is running your application has the rights to read the file

Comment: @Boris it's  showing `/opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore` and if I do ls -l then `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6446 Jul 25 14:27 /opt/server/fil/tomcat.keystore`

Comment: @cdr89 Its showing root. How do I know which user is running the app or has the permission ? Sorry I am not much familiar with linux env, tomcat and certificates.

Comment: If you're using docker, this file is supposed to be inside the container. Did you check if it's it actually there?

Comment: @cdr89+ wrong permissions (or ownership) do not ever cause ENOENT, and cannot be the issue. Plus in a docker container usually _everything_ is root and no other userids exist (but root in the container doesn't give access to anything outside unless bound by the image or container definition).

Comment: @jurez Inside the container ? Isn't the docker process server.xml path ? I am not clear here

Comment: @NoobCoder docker is a contaner, it has its own set of files, so the file in question needs to be inside of the container and not on the host.

Comment: @jurez Got it. I added that inside the container only. I have added an update in my question. Please have a look.